# Update and retrieve specific list item from sqlite database not working

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview, android-sqlite

I want to get and update data from sqlite when I click a Specific List Item in the Recycler List. The Problem comes to when I click on list Item and try to update it the data open and when I update it; It keeps the previous data and updated data in the list as empty like [![Image After Updation][1]][1]

After Doing Update the Deletion of the data from sqlite not worked; As I delete the data and press back and again open the data is still there; But as I delete the data before updation the data deleted from list as well as from list

Here is my update activity

```
public class UpdateIMEIRec extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText IMEINoUpdate,IMEIIDUpdate;
Button BtnIMEIRecUpdate;

DatabaseHelper dbHelper;
String receivedIMEIId;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_update_imeirec);
    IMEIIDUpdate= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.imeiidupdate);
    IMEINoUpdate= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.imeinumberupdate);
    BtnIMEIRecUpdate= (Button) findViewById(R.id.imeibtnupdate);

    dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    try {
        //get intent to get person id
        receivedIMEIId= getIntent().getStringExtra("IMEIID");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    User user= dbHelper.getIMEI(receivedIMEIId);

    IMEIIDUpdate.setText(user.getImeiid());
    IMEINoUpdate.setText(user.getImei());

    BtnIMEIRecUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            updateIMEIFunction();
        }
    });
}

private void updateIMEIFunction() {

    String imeiidupdate = IMEIIDUpdate.getText().toString().trim();
    String imeinumberupdate = IMEINoUpdate.getText().toString().trim();
    if(imeiidupdate.isEmpty()){
        //error name is empty
        Toast.makeText(this, "Enter IMEI ID", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    if(imeinumberupdate.isEmpty()){
        //error name is empty
        Toast.makeText(this, "Enter IMEI Number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    /*User user= new User(imeiidupdate,imeinumberupdate);*/
    User user= new User();
    dbHelper.updateIMEI(receivedIMEIId, this, user);
    FuncMoveToNextActivity();
}

private void FuncMoveToNextActivity() {
    startActivity(new Intent(UpdateIMEIRec.this,IMEIListActivity.class));
}
```

}

Here is my Database Helper Class

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
Context context;

// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "DynamicERP.db";

public  static final String table_imei = "IMEITABLE";
public  static final String table_login= "USERLOGIN";

// User Table Columns names

public static final String imeiid = "IMEIID";
public static final String imei = "IMEI";

public static final String userid = "USERID";
public static final String username = "USERNAME";
public static final String password = "PASSWORD";
public static final String userrole = "USERROLE";


// create table sql query
private static final String DATABASE_CIMEI = "CREATE TABLE " + table_imei + "("
        + imeiid + " INTEGER, " + imei + " VARCHAR );" ;

private static final String DATABASE_CUSER = "CREATE TABLE " + table_login + "("
        + userid + " INTEGER, " + username + " VARCHAR, " + password + " INTEGER, " + userrole + " VARCHAR );" ;

// drop table sql query
private String DROP_IMEI_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + table_imei;
private String DROP_USER_TABLE = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + table_login;

/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param context
 */
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CIMEI);
    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CUSER);
}


@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    //Drop User Table if exist
    db.execSQL(DROP_USER_TABLE);

    // Create tables again
    onCreate(db);

}

/**
 * This method is to create user record
 *
 * @param user
 */
public void addUser(User user) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(userid,user.getUserid());
    values.put(username, user.getName());
    values.put(password, user.getPassword());
    values.put(userrole, user.getRole());

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(table_login, null, values);
    db.close();
}

public void addIMEI(User user) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(imei,user.getImei());
    values.put(imeiid, user.getImeiid());

    // Inserting Row
    db.insert(table_imei, null, values);
    db.close();
}

/**
 * This method is to fetch all user and return the list of user records
 *
 * @return list
 */
public List<User> getAllUser() {
    // array of columns to fetch
    String[] columns = {
            userid,
            username,
            password,
            userrole
    };
    // sorting orders
    String sortOrder =
            userid + " ASC";
    List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    // query the user table
    /**
     * Here query function is used to fetch records from user table this function works like we use sql query.
     * SQL query equivalent to this query function is
     * SELECT user_id,user_name,user_email,user_password FROM user ORDER BY user_name;
     */
    Cursor cursor = db.query(table_login, //Table to query
            columns,    //columns to return
            null,        //columns for the WHERE clause
            null,        //The values for the WHERE clause
            null,       //group the rows
            null,       //filter by row groups
            sortOrder); //The sort order


    // Traversing through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            User user = new User();
            //user.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(userid))));
            user.setUserid(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(userid)));
            user.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(username)));
            user.setPassword(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(password)));
            user.setRole(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(userrole)));
            // Adding user record to list
            userList.add(user);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    // return user list
    return userList;
}



/**
 * This method is to fetch all user and return the list of user records
 *
 * @return list
 */
public List<User> getAllImei() {
    // array of columns to fetch
    String[] columns = {
            imeiid,
            imei,
    };
    // sorting orders
    String sortOrder =
            imeiid + " ASC";
    List<User> userList = new ArrayList<User>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    // query the user table
    /**
     * Here query function is used to fetch records from user table this function works like we use sql query.
     * SQL query equivalent to this query function is
     * SELECT user_id,user_name,user_email,user_password FROM user ORDER BY user_name;
     */
    Cursor cursor = db.query(table_imei, //Table to query
            columns,    //columns to return
            null,        //columns for the WHERE clause
            null,        //The values for the WHERE clause
            null,       //group the rows
            null,       //filter by row groups
            sortOrder); //The sort order


    // Traversing through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            User user = new User();
            //user.setId(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(userid))));
            user.setImei(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(imei)));
            user.setImeiid(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(imeiid)));
            // Adding user record to list
            userList.add(user);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    // return user list
    return userList;
}
/**
 * This method to check user exist or not
 *
  @param userid
 * @return true/false
 */
public boolean checkUser(String userid) {

    // array of columns to fetch
    String[] columns = {
            userid
    };
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    // selection criteria
    String selection = userid + " = ?";

    // selection argument
    String[] selectionArgs = {userid};

    // query user table with condition
    /**
     * Here query function is used to fetch records from user table this function works like we use sql query.
     * SQL query equivalent to this query function is
     * SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE imei = 'dynamic@imei.com';
     */
    Cursor cursor = db.query(table_login, //Table to query
            columns,                    //columns to return
            selection,                  //columns for the WHERE clause
            selectionArgs,              //The values for the WHERE clause
            null,                       //group the rows
            null,                      //filter by row groups
            null);                      //The sort order
    int cursorCount = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    if (cursorCount > 0) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}


/**
 * This method to check user exist or not
 *
 * @param email
 * @param password
 * @return true/false
 */
public boolean checkUser(String email, String password) {

    // array of columns to fetch

    String[] columns = {
            userid
    };
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    // selection criteria
    String selection = userid + " = ?" + " AND " + password + " = ?";

    // selection arguments
    String[] selectionArgs = {email, password};

    // query user table with conditions
    /**
     * Here query function is used to fetch records from user table this function works like we use sql query.
     * SQL query equivalent to this query function is
     * SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE user_email = 'jack@androidtutorialshub.com' AND user_password = 'qwerty';
     */
    Cursor cursor = db.query(table_login, //Table to query
            columns,                    //columns to return
            selection,                  //columns for the WHERE clause
            selectionArgs,              //The values for the WHERE clause
            null,                       //group the rows
            null,                       //filter by row groups
            null);                      //The sort order

    int cursorCount = cursor.getCount();

    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    if (cursorCount > 0) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

/**
 * This method to check user exist or not
 *
 * @param userid
 * @param username
 * @return true/false
 */
public boolean checkUserData(String userid, String username) {

    // array of columns to fetch

    String[] columns = {
            userid
    };
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    // selection criteria
    String selection = userid + " = ?" + " AND " + username + " = ?";

    // selection arguments
    String[] selectionArgs = {userid, username};

    // query user table with conditions
    /**
     * Here query function is used to fetch records from user table this function works like we use sql query.
     * SQL query equivalent to this query function is
     * SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE user_email = 'jack@androidtutorialshub.com' AND user_password = 'qwerty';
     */
    Cursor cursor = db.query(table_login, //Table to query
            columns,                    //columns to return
            selection,                  //columns for the WHERE clause
            selectionArgs,              //The values for the WHERE clause
            null,                       //group the rows
            null,                       //filter by row groups
            null);                      //The sort order

    int cursorCount = cursor.getCount();

    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    if (cursorCount > 0) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public boolean checkUserData(String userid) {
    // array of columns to fetch
    String[] columns = {
            userid
    };
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    // selection criteria
    String selection = userid + " = ?";

    // selection argument
    String[] selectionArgs = {userid};

    // query user table with condition
    /**
     * Here query function is used to fetch records from user table this function works like we use sql query.
     * SQL query equivalent to this query function is
     * SELECT user_id FROM user WHERE user_email = 'dynamic@data.com';
     */
    Cursor cursor = db.query(table_login, //Table to query
            columns,                    //columns to return
            selection,                  //columns for the WHERE clause
            selectionArgs,              //The values for the WHERE clause
            null,                       //group the rows
            null,                      //filter by row groups
            null);                      //The sort order
    int cursorCount = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    if (cursorCount > 0) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public User getUser(String id){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query= "SELECT  * FROM "+table_login+ " WHERE  userid="+ id;
    //String query= "SELECT  * FROM "+table_login+" WHERE "+imeiid +"='"+userid+"'";


    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    User userrecived = new User();
    if(cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        userrecived.setUserid(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(userid)));
        userrecived.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(username)));
        userrecived.setPassword(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(password)));
        userrecived.setRole(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(userrole)));
    }
    return userrecived;
}
public User getIMEI(String receivedIMEIId) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query= "SELECT  * FROM "+table_imei+ " WHERE  imeiid="+ receivedIMEIId;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    User imeiuser = new User();
    if(cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        imeiuser.setImeiid(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(imeiid)));
        imeiuser.setImei(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(imei)));
    }
    return imeiuser;
}


public void deletePersonRecord(String useridValue, Context mContext) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(table_login, userid + "=" + useridValue, null);
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Deleted successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    db.close();
}

public void deleteIMEIRecord(String imeiidValue, Context mContext) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM "+table_imei+" WHERE "+imeiid +"='"+imeiidValue+"'");
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Deleted successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}



public void updateIMEI(String receivedIMEIId, UpdateIMEIRec updateIMEIRec, User user) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String strSQL = "UPDATE "+table_imei+ " SET "+imei+" = "+user.getImei()+"," +
            " "+imeiid+" = "+user.getImeiid()+
            " WHERE "+imeiid+" = "+receivedIMEIId;
    db.execSQL(strSQL);
    db.close();
}

public void updateUser(String receivedUSERId, UpdateUserRec updateUserRec, User user) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String strSQL = "UPDATE "+table_login+ " SET "+username+" = "+user.getName()+"," +
            " "+password+" = "+user.getPassword()+","+userrole+" = "+user.getRole()+"" +
            " WHERE "+userid+" = "+receivedUSERId;
    db.execSQL(strSQL);
    db.close();
}
```

}

Here is my Model Class

```
public class User {

    private int id;
    private String userid;
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String role;
    private String imeiid;



    public String getImei() {
        return imei;
    }

    public void setImei(String imei) {
        this.imei = imei;
    }

    private String imei;

    public String getImeiid() {
        return imeiid;
    }

    public void setImeiid(String imeiid) {
        this.imeiid = imeiid;
    }

    public String getUserid() {
        return userid;
    }

    public void setUserid(String userid) {
        this.userid = userid;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkMxO.png
```

Comment: I have resolve the problem with getting the data from sqlite and Now I am facing the Error as I update the data two values with empty data remains in the list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below method to update data in your database and get back return status.

```
 public boolean updateUser(String receivedUSERId, UpdateUserRec updateUserRec, User user) {
    if( user!=null &&   receivedUSERId!=null){
        if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(user.getName())&&!TextUtils.isEmpty(user.getPassword())&&
        !TextUtils.isEmpty(user.getRole())){
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(username,user.getName()); 
            cv.put(password,user.getPassword());
            cv.put(userrole,user.getRole());        
            try{
                SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
                myDB.update(table_login, cv, userid+"="+receivedUSERId,null);
                myDB.commit();
                myDB.close();
                return true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Exception in update query", e.toString());
            }
        }
    }
    Log.e(TAG, "Invalid Data, Check your data first");
    return false;
}
```